# Why is my entered text in react-native SearchBar is getting cleared automatically after some milliseconds?

Tags: react-native, uisearchbar, react-native-flatlist, react-native-elements

My entered text in SearchBar is getting cleared automatically after some milliseconds when I start typing into it. It goes back to the placeholder state, what could be the issue?

Here is my code:

```
    return (
      <View style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
        <SearchBar
          placeholder="Type Here..."
          lightTheme
          round
          onChangeText={this.handleSearch}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
```

this is the code for handleSearch method,

```
handleSearch = (text) => {
    const formatQuery = text.toLowerCase();
    const data = _.filter(this.state.fullData, (user) => {
      return contains(user, formatQuery);
    });
    this.setState({ query: formatQuery, data }, () => this.makeRemoteRequest());
  };
```

code for makeRemoteRequest():

```
makeRemoteRequest = _.debounce(() => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    getUsers(20, this.state.query)
      .then((users) => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          data: users,
          fullData: users,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });
      });
  }, 250);
```

The issue persists even if I remove the debounce method so I think the issue is related to something else.
Also, this is like my 3rd day with react-native development so please excuse any newbie mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

if i am not mistaken, you should add a value prop to the SearchBar, and put a state variable like so :

```
<SearchBar
      placeholder="Type Here..."
      lightTheme
      round
      onChangeText={this.handleSearch}
      value={this.state.text} //use deconstructing
    />
```

And update it before doing your handle search

```
handleSearch = (text) => {
this.setState({text})
const formatQuery = text.toLowerCase();
const data = _.filter(this.state.fullData, (user) => {
  return contains(user, formatQuery);
});
this.setState({ query: formatQuery, data }, () => this.makeRemoteRequest());
```

};

You should check the SearchBar doc from react-native-elements : https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html